# Synclock on an object in the Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching

Can I synclock effectively on an object stored in the cache?

Like:

```
SyncLock System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("Some Object")
    'do some stuff that is threadsafe on this cached object'
End SyncLock
```

Will this stop another thread from modifying that cached object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the standard cache, yes. But it won't stop another thread replacing the object in the cache - you'll need to use a separate sync object for that. And if you happen to be using a distributed cache (e.g. Velocity) then it's not necessarily reliable either.

Comment: So... Synclocking on System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("Some Object") and then calling dim o as object = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("Some Object") could actually be referencing two different objects?

Comment: Yes, if another thread happens to set System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache("Some Object") = newObject between those two statements then you'll have locked the old object but will then retrieve and work with the new object.