# ASP.NET Caching lock mechanisme

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, locking, readerwriterlockslim

Using .NET 3.5. I'm storing customer objects in the cache using **ReaderWriterLockSlim**. The problem is that when a user from *Customer A* is doing an action that will result in a update to the customer object in the cache; the **EnterWriteLock()** will temperary stop all users from reading the customer objects from the cache eventhough they may belong to *Customer B* and have a different customer object.

Comment: The question is basically how can I some how lock the cache only for certain instances of an object.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something similar recently.  I ended up locking the object in the cache instead of the cache itself.  There are drawbacks to this approach but it might work for what you are doing.

Link (Code is VB.Net): [Synclock on an object in the Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659595/synclock-on-an-object-in-the-cache)